# jQuery .on delegation, only direct children in selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am trying to use `.on` to bind an event only to direct children of an element.

The dom looks like this:

`table > tbody > tr+ > td > table > tbody > tr+`

So far I have tried:

- `table.find(">tbody").on("dbclick", ">tr", listenerFunction);`
- `table.on("dbclick", "> tbody > tr", listenerFunction);`

None of these works as expected and using `table.on("dbclick", "tr", listenerFunction)` collides with the nested table causing double triggers and the likes because both tables have this listener.

Any ideas most appreciated.

```
<table>
  <tbody>
   <tr><!--Selectable row, adds the row after with sub table --></tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr></tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The HTML you posted is invalid. A `td` element cannot directly contain a `tr` element. Or is this just a copy and past mistake?

Comment: @FelixKling this isn't the actual code just an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your listener function use `event.stopPropagation` to stop the event bubbling back up to a parent `tr`.

```
function listenerFunc(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    // Do your thing...
}
```

Comment: I think that's the only feasible solution. Since the elements are nested, clicking on the inner `tr` would always trigger the handler of the "parent" `tr` element, no matter how the selector is constructed.

Comment: Using stopPropagation with `table.on("dbclick", "tr", listenerFunction)` did work, but I don't understand why `tbody.on("dbclick", ">tr", listenerFunction)` wouldn't work the same.

EDIT: Passing >tr as the selector to `.on` doesn't register any listeners at all which I find a little strange, seems like it should work.

Comment: @HugoT: Because events bubble. Even though `tbody.on("dbclick", ">tr", listenerFunction)` would only listen for events on the top level `tr`, the event triggered by the nested `tr` will bubble up and trigger the handler.

Comment: @HugoT the latter didn't work because two separate events were raised. The click on the `tr` which is a direct child of the child `table`, and bubbled click on the `tr` which is a direct child of the parent `table`.

Comment: @FelixKling If table T1 is the top level table and T2 is the nested table I expected the following to happen.

`T1.on("dbclick", ">tr", listenerFunction); //Triggers on rows in T1, but not rows in T2`


`T2.on("dbclick", ">tr", listenerFunction); //Triggers on rows in T2, but not in T1`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, no the later didn't work because no listeners are registered. using `tbody.on("dbclick", ">tr", listenerFunction)` with a debugger statement in listenerFunction nothing happens, the breakpoint is never hit.

Comment: @Hugo: As I said, the reason why it does not work like that is that events bubble up the DOM tree. Any click on a descendant will trigger the parent event handler. The `> tr` is only used for event delegation and basically means "if a click event is triggered inside the `tr` child". Since the `tr` are nested, the inner `tr` will trigger the handler of the outer `tr`. See the difference between `> tr` and `tr` here: http://jsfiddle.net/BGUAr/, http://jsfiddle.net/BGUAr/1/. Click on both, "Outer" and "Inner". `tr` will trigger the handler twice, `> tr` only once.

Comment: @Hugo: Maybe these links help: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html, http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/.

Comment: @FelixKling You are correct about the event bubbling and as you said event.stopPropagation() stops this, I am still confused about the `> tr` version not registering a single listener though.

Comment: @FelixKling Yeah it does which is a little strange, all though the DOM  in my example is dumbed down, I guess something is amiss. Anyway this answer solves it for now. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @FelixKling Turns out is was a bug in 1.7.2.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to either add an `id` or `class` to the child table. This would ensure that it doesn't conflict with any other element on the page or any modification that happens in future. Suppose you add a class `nested-table` to child table. The code will look like this:

```
$('table.nested-table tr').dblclick(listenerFunc)
```

As you have indicated that you reference to table, this should work:

> table.on('dblclick', 'tr', listenerFunc)

Comment: In my example the table variable already refers to the table uniquely. Also maybe it's not clear from the post, but the rows are not present when the listener is added.

Comment: The reason why your code did not work is due to '> tr', which means direct child of the target element

Comment: Nope the reason was due to a bug in jQuery 1.7.2/3, see my answer.

Comment: I agree with your statement on bug in JQuery on direct descendant (>). However, the solution I gave above is working. I modified your fiddle. See http://jsfiddle.net/MALNc/4/

Answer (score 0):

If your first `<table>` is not nested itself, you can provide a selector that only matches `<tr>` elements that are not descendants of other `<tr>` elements:

```
table.on("dbclick", "tr:not(tr tr)", listenerFunction);
```

Comment: Would probably work, but both tables run identical code as these tables can be created on the fly, therefor I cannot take in to consideration the depth of a table.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var table = $('#tbl')
table.on("click", "> tbody > tr", listenerFunction);

function listenerFunction(e){
    if(!$(this).children().filter($(e.target).closest('td')).length){
        return;
    }
    console.log('direc tr')
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/KCNT6/)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this is in part me forgetting to prevent event bubbling and in part a bug/missing feature in jquery 1.7.

The same code in two jsfiddles

- [jQuery 1.7.2](http://jsfiddle.net/WnN3Y/3/)
- [jQuery 1.9.1](http://jsfiddle.net/MALNc/3/)

In jQuery 1.7.2 passing ">tr" as the selector to `.on` does not work, I do not know if this is a bug or something that's just not implement in 1.7.2 however the `.on` method was added in 1.7.

The following code reproduces the error. I've tested this on Chrome running on Mountain Lion and Chrome running on window 7

HMTL:

```
<table id="outer">
    <tbody>
        <tr id="outer-row">
            <td>Hello</td>
            <td>World</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="outer-row-1">
            <td>
                <table id="inner">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr id="inner-row">
                            <td>nested
                            </td>
                         </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    var handle = function(e) {
        console.dir(this.id);
    };


    $("#outer").children("tbody").on("dblclick", ">tr", handle);
    $("#inner").children("tbody").on("dblclick", ">tr", handle);
});
```